How input in textarea without refresh
How input param with input in textarea  without refresh
$ArNumbers->int2str($params);
No other file send


   <input id="textbox" name="textbox" type="text"> 

<button onclick="convertToCm()">Convert to cm</button> <div id="resullt">result</div>



`let textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
let result = document.getElementById("result");
function convertToCm() {
value = textbox.value;
result.innerHTML = +value; } `

Please use markdown to distinguish code from prose.

Also please use clearer phrasing in the title line
